# Count number of occurrences with specific conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, where-clause

From the dataset below, I need to know

> How many providers have a positive response in Number 4 and Number 5.The positive response for Number 4 and Number 5 need to have occurred on the same Sheet.
> For example the below scenario would qualify for this condition (has to be in the same Offer):

```
SELECT 'CFC _EEU' AS PROVIDER, 'Offer 1' AS SHEET,  4 AS NUMBER, 'yes' AS RESPONSE
UNION
SELECT 'CFC _EEU' AS PROVIDER, 'Offer 1' AS SHEET,  5 AS NUMBER, 'yes' AS RESPONSE
```

Below the dataset, then what I tried:

```
SELECT  'CFB_CSS'    AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFC _EEU'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFC _EEU'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFC _EEU'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFC _EEU'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 2'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFC _EEU'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 3'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 2'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 2'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 3'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 3'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 4'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 4'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 5'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 5'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 6'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 6'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 7'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 7'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 8'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 8'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 9'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 9'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 2'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 3'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFE _TSS'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 4'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 5'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 6'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 7'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 8'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 9'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE 



SELECT [PROVIDER],[SHEET],[Number],[RESPONSE]  
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by [PROVIDER]) -
              row_number() over (partition by [SHEET]order by [PROVIDER])
             ) as grp
              from Test t
             --WHERE  ([Number] =4 AND [Response] ='yes') and 
    --               ([Number] =5 AND [Response] ='yes')
     ) t
group by grp, [PROVIDER],[SHEET],[Number],[RESPONSE] ;
```

I can't figure out how to implement my condition:

```
WHERE  ([Number] = 4 AND [Response] = 'yes') and 
       ([Number] = 5 AND [Response] = 'yes')
```

Comment: If you're looking to include both 4 and 5 you probably want to change your condition to OR `WHERE  ([Number] = 4 AND [Response] = 'yes') OR  ([Number] = 5 AND [Response] = 'yes')`

Comment: no both conditions need to be met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses `exists`:

```
select count(distinct provider)
from mytable t
where t.number = 4 and t.response = 'yes' and exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.provider = t.provider and t1.sheet = t.sheet and t1.number = 5 and t1.response = 'yes'
)
```

This counts provider that have at least one sheet with both numbers and a positive response on each.

An alternative is two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(distinct provider)
from (
    select provider
    from mytable t
    where number in (4, 5) and response = 'yes'
    group by provider, sheet
    having min(number) <> max(number)
) t
```

Comment: this does not work, as ([Number] = 4 AND [Response] = 'yes') and 
       ([Number] = 5 AND [Response] = 'yes') needs to be included. I am trying to work on your code, but I am not getting the desired result

Comment: Like I am saying above, a case like this would meet the criteria: SELECT 'CFC _EEU' AS PROVIDER, 'Offer 1' AS SHEET,  4 AS NUMBER, 'yes' AS RESPONSE
UNION
SELECT 'CFC _EEU' AS PROVIDER, 'Offer 1' AS SHEET,  5 AS NUMBER, 'yes' AS RESPONSE

Comment: @Anna: ok, I added a condition to filter on positive responses only, which was missing in the original queries.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this query and look at the results.  It appears to me these are the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT * into #tmp FROM (
SELECT 'CFB_CSS' AS PROVIDER, 'Offer 1' AS SHEET, 4 AS NUMBER, 'no' AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFC _EEU'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFC _EEU'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFC _EEU'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFC _EEU'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 2'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFC _EEU'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 3'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 2'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 2'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 3'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 3'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 4'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 4'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 5'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 5'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 6'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 6'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 7'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 7'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 8'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 8'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 9'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 9'   AS SHEET,   5   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 2'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 3'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFE _TSS'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 1'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'no'    AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 4'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 5'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 6'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 7'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 8'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE     UNION
SELECT  'CFD _PLL'   AS PROVIDER,   'Offer 9'   AS SHEET,   4   AS NUMBER,  'yes'   AS RESPONSE) as tmp

select *
into #tmp2
from (
    select * from #tmp
    where RESPONSE = 'yes'
    ) t
PIVOT(
    COUNT(response)
    FOR NUMBER IN (
        [Num4],
        [Num5])
) AS pivot_table;

select * from #tmp2
```

If those are the results you are looking for, then the following query will give you the final results:

```
select *
from #tmp2
where Num4 > 0 and Num5 > 0
```